# Regarding $n$-tuples for defining points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there some way to prove that exactly $n$ numbers are needed to define a point in a space $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Using Cartesian systems, this is intuitive for $n=2$ and $n=3$, but how can we prove it for higher dimensions?

Comment: read about basis

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “a space $\mathbb R^n$” here? Depending on how you do that, there might be nothing to prove. That aside, there are some basic theorems that make “dimension” a well-defined concept.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the space $\mathbb R^n$ is defined precisely as $\underbrace{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times\dotsm\times\mathbb R}_{n\text{ times}}$, which of course tells you that precisely $n$ numbers deetermine a point. Of course, to formally show that some smarter choice of representing variables won't be able to reduce the number or increase it, some linear algebra is required (in particular, the theorem that any basis of a finite dimensional vector space has the same number of vectors).

Comment: When you say space what exactly do you mean? are you referring to a Vector Space? $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set (not a space). The set can be used in a Vector Space with the addition of certain operators (scalar multiplication and vector addition).

Comment: If you want someone to prove something about $\mathbb R^n,$ first make sure we all know what you mean by $\mathbb R^n.$ In addition to stating the formal definition, it might help to explain where you encountered $\mathbb R^n$ and why you are unsure of the answer to this question. That's what we call "context" for a question on stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

This generally follows from the fact that an $n$-dimensional vector space needs a basis set of $n$ vectors to span it. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is, of course, $n$ dimensional. The related proofs can be found in any half-decent introductory text on linear algebra.

The end result is that any point in the vector space, such as the $n$-tuples in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you're concerned with, can be considered as a vector, and, as that vector is in the span of the basis set, then you can write it as a linear combination of those basis vectors.

As a simple example that touches on what I mean by this, we typically we represent points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$. This can be translated as being the sum of the usual basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a unit vector along each axis:

- $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, ..., 0)$
- $e_2 = (0, 1, 0, ..., 0)$
- $e_3 = (0, 0, 1, ..., 0)$
- $e_k = \text{vector of n components, all zero except for a 1 at the k-th place}$
- $e_n = (0, 0, 0, ..., n)$

Thus, considering the $n$ tuple $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ as a vector,

$$(x_1, ..., x_n) = x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + ... x_ne_n$$

Of course, this is just one way of presenting this $n$-tuple, dependent on this basis. Change the basis set - the $e_k$'s above - and you will need a different calculation. But since

$$dim(V) = n \iff \text{V's basis set requires n vectors}$$

for any vector space $V$ (here, $V = \mathbb{R}^n$), then each point will always be the linear combination of $n$ vectors.

Comment: Why are you using a vector to describe a tuple here? The OP speaks about an n-tuple NOT a vector. If you want to use it as you have here you must first establish that there is a direct isomorphism between the two. You have merely stated it here without proof.

Comment: on top of which you are using scalar multiplication and vector addition to construct a tuple.

Comment: $e_n$ is incorrect here too. The $nth$ element should be $1$ not $n$.  Why too are you using tuple and vector notations interchangeably here? The conventional notation is $\underline{e}_i$ and it should be $\underline{e}_i = \left[0, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots 0\right]^T$